# Newline characters disappear after uploading a txt to a server

Tags: javascript, d3.js, newline, xss, plaintext

Can't parse any data from a `txt` file (not a `csv` for a reason) when it's uploaded to a server  because all the newline characters a apparently gone. `d3.js` parser that I'm using `parseRows` does not work properly without them.
On a localserver everything seems to be fine.

```
d3.text('fileName.txt', 'text/plain', function(fileContent) {
    console.log(/\n/.test(fileContent));
});

[localserver]: true
[onlineserver]: false
```

Using free hosting on Hostinger, `Apache` server according to Wappalyzer. Don't know much about it.
Tried different encodings. No luck.

**Update:**
I downloaded the txt back from the server and opened it in Sublime Text. No newline characters in it. The exact local copy is fine.

**Solved by avoiding:** Decided to save some time and nerve and uploaded my txts to Dropbox. In case someone has same problems, here is a little trick to get direct links to Dropbox files http://techapple.net/2014/04/trick-obtain-direct-download-links-dropbox-files-dropbox-direct-link-maker-tool-cloudlinker/

**Also solved by berserking:** Changing the extension of the file (to `csv` for example) also helps, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is probably trying to sanitize the strings it receives from the UI in order to prevent things like cross-site attacks.
Trying to escape the string you send to the server with [encodeUri(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and if you need to [decodeUri(decodedStr)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)